# How to plot overlap clustering with a list of vertices of each group and the edge list by R?

Tags: r, igraph

I have a file csv including edge list of graph. After implementing CONGA 
(Clustering Overlap Girven-NewMan alorithm), result is a list of vertices of each group. 
I don't know how to plot it so that each group has different color in graph by R.
I can plot graph with edge list in R, but I don't know how to mark vertices in each group.
Input: edge list file and list of vertices in each group.
Output: graph with different color for each group.
[output nearly like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ScoeC.png)
My English isn't good. Thanks for your support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You plot colors using `$color` of vertices. Try to assign a color like `V(g)$color <- 'green'`.

It is better if you give us some code.

You say you get a list of your group-members. Convert the list to a vector, and sign a new color to each unique group-member value. I wrote this example code. I think it shows what you're after.

```
library(igraph)
get_a_random_network <- function() {
  # EN: Function to get some random data to use as an example
  g <- erdos.renyi.game(100, 60, type="gnm", directed=F, loops=FALSE)
  g <- g %>% delete_vertices( V(g)[degree(g)==0] )

  (g)
}

# Get sample data
g <- get_a_random_network()
# Use a cluster algorythm to determine groups. You said you had a list. I use this to generate example data.
groups <- cluster_fast_greedy(g)

# Look at the vertecies
(V(g))
# Look at what groups they belong to:
(groups$membership)

# Here you write that you have "list of vertices of each group". You don't
# give us code, but I assume that you have data that looks like this:
CONGA_list <- lapply(1:max(groups$membership),function(x) V(g)[groups$membership ==x])
(CONGA_list)
# This is where you should really have provided a code example.

# You could convert a list like CONGA_list to a vector like this:
membership_groups <- rep(0, length(V(g)))
for(x in 1:length(CONGA_list)){
  membership_groups[as.vector(CONGA_list[[x]])] <- x
}
(membership_groups == groups$membership)

# You give color to your network by first telling each vector which group it belongs to
V(g)$membership <- groups$membership
# Then we asign a color. I use a vector of R-colors which I get like this...
colors = grDevices::colors()[grep('gr(a|e)y', grDevices::colors(), invert = T)]
# ... and then I sample from them to give each vertecy a color.
colors <- sample(colors, max(V(g)$membership))
V(g)$color <- colors[V(g)$membership]
(V(g)$color)

# The plot will work with the colors in V(g)$color
plot(g, vertex.size=7, vertex.label=NA)
```

Good luck

Comment: Thanks for ur answer, this help me a lot. But list of vertices saved in .txt file like this: 


UID100000802621148 UID100002779058911 UID100002789611990 UID100002804260707 UID100003095978500 UID100003176527035
......


each group's member is a line.
I don't how to read and convert it like CONGA_list in ur answer.
Sorry for this, but I'm a newbie in R. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Ah. Your question said "list of vertecies". Maybe read up on basic data formats in R. Post a specific question like "How do I read this text file to use as group-assignment in Igraph in R?". post the code and the example data.